# Is it possible to bundle a Play! application into a single executable?

Tags: scala, web-applications, playframework

I'm building an application using Scala + [Play!](http://www.playframework.com/).  This is not a normal web application.  Instead, it's just a software that will do something on localhost.  In other words it will be distributed to multiple clients' machines.  As a result, I want it to be really portable and light-weight.  I don't want the clients to have to manually install Scala, Play, and JVM before they can run the program.

So my question is, is there a way to bundle a Play! application into a single executable?  It doesn't really have to be just a single file, i.e. it just have to be really easy for a client with little technical knowledge to run this application easily.

Hope I'm being clear...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or maybe you are just looking for a way to easily `dist` your application? :) have a look here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ProductionDist

This will produce a self-contained .zip file in your project's brand new `dist` sub directory. The only thing missing in that archive would be the JVM

Comment: +1. If there's something built into play already, ppl should try that first.

Answer (score 2):

You could use things like [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager) and [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly).